# after selector width height automatically set to 0px windows chrome only

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm getting a strange behavior in windows chrome only. This check in the checkbox is rendering as 0px x 0px in the after selector. If I try to force width and height I still get the same issue.

[image]

All other browsers it renders like this

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<label class="checkbox ng-isolate-scope ng-valid" ng-model="result.selected">
  <span class="checkbox-styled-container">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-styled-inverted ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" ng-model="ngModel" style="">
    <span></span>
  </span>
</label>

.checkbox-styled:checked + span:after, .checkbox-styled-container input[type='checkbox']:checked + span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 7px;
    top: 4px;
    left: 3px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a span, so it has a default `display:inline;`
Try to add `display:block;` in the css class to force the span to display as a block

Comment: Thank you @Finrod, applied it to this <span class="checkbox-styled-container"> and it worked!